# In C, is it possible access a variable name at run time via pointer

Tags: c, structure

In C, I want to access a variable name at run time. 
For instance there is a structure abc

```
struct alpha
{
    int aaa1,
    int aaa2,
    char bbb1
};

struct alpha alp;
char *ptr_alpha =&alp;
```

Is it possible I can use any expression like

```
if (alpha element1 name == "aaa1")
{
    do this;
}
else
{
    do that;
}
```

Comment: You should `do that;` on `else` ;)

Comment: No. Everything else in this comment is written just to get enough characters.

Comment: tell us what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Why should your program logic bother about the variable name?

Comment: If you could, the optimizer would remove the `if/else`, because *surely* this resolves to a constant case: `if ((nameof(alpha.aaa1)=='aaa1')..` -- which is *always* true or *always* false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Since this is C, you have to use `struct alpha` to declare variables (since you did not create a typedef such as `typedef struct alpha alpha;`). C++ would allow the notation without the `struct` even without a `typedef`.  You also cannot compare strings like that in C (meaningfully); you need to use `strcmp()` or something similar.  If you are trying to determine that `aaa1` is the first member of `struct alpha`, you'd probably need to use `offsetof(struct alpha, aaa1) == 0` as the condition. That does not generalize well, though.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for editing the question for better view and eveyone else for response. I think I was missing the exact case I want to run therefore HAL asked for bothering about variable. I am having a requirement in which I have very large structure with structures and variables. I need to fill those from xml or any other means at run time. But to fill value I would be requiring to write name of each and every element. So if I had 100 variables inside sub structures , I will have a diverse path for each element. I just want to find out a logic, so that need not to write full name every time

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make any sense to access a variable name in runtime. Every beginner gets this idea at some point, but it originates from lack of understanding of what goes on "underneath the hood". Identifiers such a variable names, function names, types etc only exist in your source code. They are there to help the programmer. In the compiled binary, there isn't a trace left of any identifiers.

There are various language mechanisms that should be used for what you try to achieve: enums, pointers, function pointers and so on. As for your specific case, there is too little information about what you are trying to achieve, to give a suggestion about how to solve it.

Comment: Yes Lundin you are correct about the fact that after compilation identifiers name etc doesn't exist in the code.

Comment: The scenario which I want to run is fill value from xml to structure element. Like :- xml tag in xml file <aaa1>1</aaa1> and in code alp.aaa1 = read_value_from_xml;  

If there are 100 diff elements then I have to write this piece of code for every element like

alp1.aaa2 = read_value_from_xml;

alp1.bbb1 = read_value_from_xml;

and so on

I just want to write a logic so that need not to write this code again and again.

Comment: @user2448138 If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you only need an array of character pointers. Possibly allocate memory dynamically for every string as you go. Read the file line by line. Then use a lookup table to determine where in the array some particular data is located.

Comment: @Lundin: In all fairness, there are languages that support this -- Python, for example. It can be handy when debugging or writing tests -- the test can output the name of the function that was just tested, alongside whether it passed or failed.

Answer (score 2):

Names of identifiers are not known to a compiled program (ignoring dlsym magic), so no, there is no way to test for access to certain struct members at runtime. But if you just need to select members according to some string, then

```
 if (strcmp (user_input, "aaa1") == 0) {
        /* do something to alp->aaa1 */
 } else if (strcmp (user_input, "aaa2") == 0) {
        /* do something to alp->aaa2 */
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are usually ways to do everything if you put your mind to it.  It's just that sometimes the cure is worse than the disease as it were.

I've been involved with a legitimate reason to do something like this in the past, and the best solution we came up with was to literally parse the header file(s) defining your data in question.

It's not an easy problem to solve; when you parse your header, you're going to need to take note of the following:  variable name, variable type, and any possible padding that may occur.  As you parse each element, you save an offset you keep track of so that when you get your name later on, you stuff the value into something like:  `(unsigned char *)(&data_structure + var_offset)`.

When you're parsing your xml, then you'll look up the element name, and call a handler (that you write) for putting the data in for each type of data you need to support.  Most commonly you'd probably need an `int` handler and a `char *` (or whatever) handler.  Bonus points for implementing simple defines (usually as constant values for array sizes (oh yeah, you'll have to implement arrays, especially for `char *` strings), etc.) and recursive processors that implement previously-defined struct types referred to by later structs.

Quick example:  Your token def would be something like:

```
struct token_def
{
    char *token_name;
    enum supported_token_types token_type;
    int array_length;
    int token_offset;
}
```

and your example struct would therefore fill in as

```
{
    { "aaa1", TT_INT, 1, 0 },
    { "aaa2", TT_INT, 1, 4 },
    { "bbb1", TT_CHAR, 1, 8 },
}
```

etc.  If you had a bbb2 element that was a 10-byte string after that, then it might look like:

```
    { "bbb2", TT_CHAR, 10, 9 },
```

Although that 9 is going to be dependent on padding rules, and could possibly be like 12 or something.  Padding will probably be your hardest problem to solve, although in reality it's fairly straightforward if you "get it."

I seem to recall there may be a library that does this for you already, but I couldn't find it with a quick search.  Good luck.